# Sitecore Powershell Deserialization

Tags: powershell, serialization, sitecore

I am trying to perform deserialization with Sitecore Powershell Extensions 251. I cant get deserialization to work. Here is what I did :

- I serialized the item sitecore\content\settings\testItem. Serialization was successful, package was created.

  Get-Item "master:\content\settings\testItem" | Serialize-Item -Recurse
- I delete the item sitecore\content\settings\testItem and try to deserialize it with the command :

  Deserialize-Item -Path master:\content\settings\TestItem -Recurse

I get the following exception :

```
writeErrorStream      : True
Exception             : System.Exception: path is not under the root
                           bei Sitecore.Data.Serialization.PathUtils.GetShortPath(String path)
                           bei Sitecore.Data.Serialization.Manager.LoadTree(String path, LoadOptions options)
                           bei Cognifide.PowerShell.PowerShellIntegrations.Commandlets.Serialization.DeserializeItemCommand.Deserialize(String path)
                           bei Cognifide.PowerShell.PowerShellIntegrations.Commandlets.Serialization.DeserializeItemCommand.ProcessRecord()
                           bei System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Deserialize-Item], Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Cognifide.PowerShell.PowerShellIntegrations.Commandlets.Serialization.DeserializeItemCommand
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1}
PSMessageDetails      :
```

I have searched the web, but I could not find documentation/examples for deserialization. Can anyone write me how to do the deserialization, and if available, refer to the documentation or example resources on the web?`

Thanx

Comment: I have already tried that : Deserialize-Item -Path master:\\content\settings -Recurse. I get the same exception.

Comment: If you didn't serialize Settings item before - it might fail as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`deserialize-item` coomand requires 2 parameters:

1. `Path` - path on the hard drive to the **directory**
2. `Root` - the location of the `serialization` directory

and `Recurse` optionally, e.g:

```
deserialize-item -Path "C:\project\data\serialization\master\sitecore\content\settings" -Root "C:\project\data\serialization\" -Recurse
```

Update the beginning of the page in the code above so they match your environment.

Here is a blog post explaining [serialization and deserialization with Sitecore Powershell Extensions](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/serialization-and-deserialization-with-sitecore-powershell-extensions/).